# General formula for $\sin\left(k\arcsin (x)\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to rewrite this in terms of $k$ and $x$, especially as a polynomial. It seems to me to crop up every so often, especially for $k=2$, when I integrate with trig substitution. But $k=2$ is not so bad, because I can use the double angle formula; it's the prospect of higher values of $k$ that motivates this question.

I think the law of sines may help? Or maybe even De Moivre's theorem, to find the length of the hypotenuse as the length of the angle changes, if we think of the right triangle drawn from $\arcsin(x)$ with side1 = $x$, hypotenuse = $1$, and side2 = $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ as a complex number, though I'm not sure how that might work.

Comment: Maybe this will help.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos x$$
and:
$$ \sin(m\arccos(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2} U_{m-1}(x), \qquad \cos(m\arccos x)=T_m(x), $$
where $T_m$ and $U_{m-1}$ are [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first and second kind, respectively.

So we simply have:

> $$\sin(m\arcsin x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}T_m(x)&\text{ if }&m\equiv 1\pmod{4},\\ \sqrt{1-x^2} U_{m-1}(x)&\text{ if }&m\equiv 2\pmod{4},\\-T_m(x)&\text{ if }&m\equiv 3\pmod{4},\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2} U_{m-1}(x)&\text{ if }&m\equiv 0\pmod{4}.  \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 5):

Funny coincidence: just saw this
formula of Euler's
on page 240 of the current
(August 2014)
Fibonacci Quarterly:

$\sin(ma)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{m}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^n\sin^{2n+1}(a) \prod_{k=1}^{n}(m^2-(2k-1)^2) 
$.

Putting
$a = \sin^{-1}(x)$,
so $x = \sin(a)$,
this becomes

$\sin(m\sin^{-1}x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{m}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^nx^{2n+1} \prod_{k=1}^{n}(m^2-(2k-1)^2) 
$.

Note that there are
only a finite number of terms
if $m$ is an odd integer.

A quite reasonable proof
of Euler's formula
is given in the paper.

(added later)

Here is the proof:

Let 
$f(a) = \sin(m \sin^{-1}(\sin(a)))$
or
$f(x) = \sin(m \sin^{-1}(\sin(x)))$
.

Differentiating w.r.t. $x$,
we get
$f'(x)
=m(1-x^2)^{-1/2} \cos(m \sin^{-1}(x))
$
and
$f''(x)
=m x (1-x^2)^{-3/2}\cos(m\sin^{-1}(x))-m^2(1-x^2)^{-1}\sin(m\sin^)-1)(x))
$
$
=x(1-x^2)^{-1}f'(x) - m^2(1-x^2)^{-1}f(x)
$.

In other
words,
$f''(x)-P(x)f'(x)+Q(x)f(x) = 0$,
where $P(x) = x/(1-x^2)$
and
$Q(x) = m^2/(1-x^2)$.
Since the denominators of
$P$ and $Q$
are non-zero at $0$,
these are analytic there.
Thus,
$x=0$ 
is an ordinary point of the
differential equation
$$(1-x^2)f''(x) - xf'(x) + m^2 f(x) = 0
$$
so there is a
power series solution
of the form
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_n x^n
$.

Substituting this,
we get
$$u_{n+2}
=-\dfrac{m^2-n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}u_n
, n \ge 0
.
$$

Since
$u_0
=f(0)
=\sin(m  \sin^{-1}(0))
= 0
$,
$u_{2n} = 0$
for all $n$.

Since
$u_1
=f'(0)
=m(1-0^2)^{-1/2}
= m
$,
$u_{2n+1} 
$
is given by the formula
for all $n$.

Comment: So, for even m, there are an infinite number of terms? For m = 2, is that because it refers to the power series of $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$? How can I know what the original function is from the expansion, for arbitrary even m? And was this formula derived using Euler's formula?

Comment: The series terminates only for odd integral m. Note that m does not have to be an integer.

Comment: Added the proof of the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I really meant to ask, though, about even integral m. Though the series will not terminate, I'm sure it can still be expressed as an elementary function, just like how it was with m=2. Is there a simple way to know what this function is?

Comment: Don't know. Can you do it for m=4?

Comment: I can apply the double angle formula twice. Knowing that $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$ and $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, I'll write $\sin(4\arcsin(x)) = 2\sin(2\arcsin(x))\cos(2\arcsin(x)) = 2 [2\sin(\arcsin(x))\cos(\arcsin(x))] [(\cos(\arcsin(x)))^2 - (\sin(\arcsin(x)))^2]$. After substitution, this gives $4x\sqrt{1-x^2}(1-x^2-x^2) = 4x\sqrt{1-x^2} - 8x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Using the recurrence relation thing Alex mentioned, I can do something like this for any integer m. Do you think I can go backwards? i.e. given the series from the formula you gave, get this function?

Comment: But this is not a polynomial, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Well, I admit I did start asking a different question in the comment thread, which amounts to "If a power series refers to that of an elementary function, how can you tell what that elementary function is?" Oh well. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I would try to write $A[k](x)=\sin (k.\arcsin(x) )$ and $B[k](x)=\cos (k.\arcsin (x) )$

and then $A[k+1](x) = \sin ( \arcsin(x) + k.\arcsin (x) ) = x B[k](x) + \sqrt{1-x^2} A[k](x)$

You could then either use the same recurrence form for $B[k+1](x)$ and have a double recurrence relation, or use $B[k](x)=\sqrt{1-A[k](x)^2}$ and have a simple one

Answer (score 1):

Consider the differential equation
$$
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+k^2y=0
$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Letting $y=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$ gives
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia_ix^{i-1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^{i-2}.
$$
Now substituting we get
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x^2)\sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^{i-2}-x\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia_ix^{i-1}+k^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i&=0
\\\iff \sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^{i-2}-\sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia_ix^{i}+k^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i&=0
\\\iff \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+2)(i+1)a_{i+2}x^{i}-\sum_{i=2}^\infty i^2a_ix^{i}+\sum_{i=2}^\infty ia_ix^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty ia_ix^{i}+k^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i&=0
\\\iff (2a_2+k^2a_0)+(6a_3+k^2a_1-a_1)x+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} ((i+2)(i+1)a_{i+2}+(k^2-i^2)a_i)x^i&=0
\\\iff\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ((i+2)(i+1)a_{i+2}+(k^2-i^2)a_i)x^i&=0.
\end{align}
$$
As this is an identity, we need each coefficient to be 0 giving
$$
a_{i+2}=-\frac{(k+i)(k-i)}{(i+2)(i+1)}a_i
$$
$\forall i \geqslant 0$. At this point, we can freely choose $a_0,a_1\in\mathbb{R}$ as seed values, where each choice would yield a unique solution, subsequently leading to expressions for every even and odd coefficient, respectively. The specific solution we require is such that when $x=0, y=\sin(k\arcsin(0))=0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{kcos(k\arcsin(0))}{\sqrt{1-0^2}}=k$, so if this is indeed the case, we have
$$
\begin{align}
a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i(0)^{i}&=a_0=0
\\a_1+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}ia_i(0)^{i-1}&=a_1=k
\end{align}
$$
from the power series for $y$ evaluated at $x=0$.
Now we have
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2}=-\frac{(k+0)(k-0)}{(0+2)(0+1)}a_0=0
\\\implies a_{4}=-\frac{(k+2)(k-2)}{(2+2)(2+1)}a_2=0
\\\vdots
\\\implies a_{2n}=0
\end{align}
$$
$\forall n\geqslant0$ and setting $i=2n-1$,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n+1}&=-\frac{(k+(2n-1))(k-(2n-1))}{((2n-1)+2)((2n-1)+1)}a_{2(n-1)+1}
\\&=\cdots
\\&=a_1\prod_{l=1}^{n}\left(-\frac{(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1))}{((2l-1)+2)((2l-1)+1)}\right)
\\&=k(-1)^n\left(\prod_{l=1}^{n}(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1))\right)\left(\prod_{l=1}^{n}(2l+1)(2l)\right)^{-1}
\\&=\frac{k(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{l=1}^{n}(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1))
\\&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{k(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\prod_{l=1}^{n}(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1)) , & k>2n-1\ \lor \ k\equiv0\pmod{2}
\\ 0, & k \leqslant 2n-1 \ \land \ k\equiv1\pmod{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
$\forall n\geqslant 0$. Note that all the odd coefficients are non-zero when $k$ is even, as clearly $k-(2l-1)$ could never be $0$, i.e. we obtain an infinite power series. However, whenever $k=2j-1$ for some $j$, we have $a_{2n+1}=0 \ \forall n \geqslant j=\frac{k+1}{2}$, as $2j-1-(2l-1)=2(j-l)$ would be $0$ when $l=j$ (which will be achieved for $n\geqslant j$ as $1\leqslant l\leqslant n$). In this case we obtain a polynomial.
So
$$
\sin(k\arcsin x)=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\prod_{l=1}^{n}(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1))\right)x^{2n+1}, & k\equiv0\pmod{2}
\\\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{k(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\prod_{l=1}^{n}(k+(2l-1))(k-(2l-1))\right)x^{2n+1}, &  k\equiv1\pmod{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Rather similar to the answer by marty cohen below.